# How to pull a specific object from a csv file?

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to get a specific part of this csv file but I cant get it to work correctly. when I try to pull a piece of it I get the entire column. Here is what the file looks like and my code:

[Demand.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjPEX.png)

```
Time,Day ahead forecast,Hour ahead forecast,Current demand
00:00,23307,22058,21942
00:05,21744,21822,21849
00:10,21744,21822,21908
00:15,21744,21822,21809
00:20,21744,21615,21736
00:25,21744,21615,21688
00:30,21744,21615,21563
00:35,21744,21371,21479
00:40,21744,21371,21378
00:45,21744,21371,21256
```

code

```
const fs=require('fs')
const csv = require('csv-parser');


fs.createReadStream('demand.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', function(data){
    try {
        console.log(data.Time[1]);  
    }
    catch(err) {
        //error handler
        console.log('error');
    }
     })
  .on('end', function() {
    //some final operation
});
```

The Output is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
```

and so on till the it reaches the end of the CSV.

I have tried a couple different ways and nothing seems to have worked. I am very new to Javascript so any help is appreciated. an example of what I need is something that can pull row 3 column 1. 00:10 being the output. Thank you.

Comment: can you show what your console log is printing ?

Comment: console.log(data.Time[1]), Are you trying to get the first column's first value?

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the 'CSV' file: your screenshot shows you had to enable multiple separator options (commas AND tabs) to use your import tool.

Try sticking to one separator: comma

```
Time,Day ahead forecast,Hour ahead forecast,Current demand
00:00,23307,22058,21942
00:05,21744,21822,21849
00:10,21744,21822,21908
00:15,21744,21822,21809
00:20,21744,21615,21736
00:25,21744,21615,21688
00:30,21744,21615,21563
00:35,21744,21371,21479
00:40,21744,21371,21378
00:45,21744,21371,21256
```

Comment: Yup, there is no constancy  `Time    Day ahead forecast, Hour ahead forecast,    Current demand` .

Comment: This was an error on my part. I didnt catch the formatting as I pasted it in place. The file itself is formatted correctly. The solution by @kemotoe worked for overall expected output. I now have the problem of obtaining data from the columns that have spaces in the Column Name.

Answer (score 0):

It appears [`csv-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) parses the csv into an array of objects.

To access row 3 column 1 it would be

```
console.log(data[3].Time);
```

Data is an `array` with each element corresponding to a 'row' of data. So to access row 3 it would be `data[3]` etc.

Each individual 'column' is accessed by the object `key` or the column header from each column in the `csv`.

To access object keys with spaces you can use "bracket notation"

```
console.log(data[3].['Day ahead forecast']);
```

Comment: This worked perfect for selecting the row and value for the column. I was thinking that the array would be the column name and not the row. Thank you. Is the key indexed as well because now I have problems with the column having spaces in the name.

Comment: Turns out with csv-parse, I can remap the headers to custom defined ones and pull the column that way. This will work perfectly

Comment: @Rtmott edited the answer to include accessing object keys with spaces

Answer (score 0):

So the issue could be due to no constancy `Time Day ahead forecast, Hour ahead forecast, Current demand.`
You can fix this just like @searlea suggested with`comma, tab, or evn with pipe` separated.

Here's a working example.

https://repl.it/@subhendukundu/PaleWelcomeChord

Comment: This Worked beautifully, Thank you!